# Joint probability of pairs in R

Tags: r, statistics, probability, data-transform

I have a matrix that has consecutive pairs of values from a sequence.

For example, in a sequence like `[1,1,3,3,3,4,4,2,4,2,2]`, I would have the following pairs stored in a matrix.

```
1, 1
1, 3
3, 3
3, 3
3, 4
4, 4
4, 2
2, 4
4, 2
2, 2
```

And, I want to get the probability of occurrence for each unique pair.

For example, for a pair like `(a,b)`, the `joint_prob(a,b) = cond_prob(b|a)/prob(a)`

```
(1,1) 0.5
(1,3) 0.5
(3,3) 0.6
and so on..
```

Is there anyway I can do this in R without having to use many loops? By using built in libraries? Could someone help me do this in an efficient way?

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me how the second column is generated from the sequence. It seems that the first column is the sequence minus the last element, and second is the sequence minus the first. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. That's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
d <- c(1,1,3,3,3,4,4,2,4,2,2)
tr <- NULL
for (i in 1:(length(d)-1)) {  # all bigrams
  tr <- rbind(tr, data.frame(x=d[i], y=d[i+1]))
}
tbl <- table(tr)
joint_prob <- tbl / rowSums(tbl) # joint probability table
joint_prob[1,1]
# 0.5
joint_prob[1,3]
# 0.5
joint_prob[3,3]
# 0.6666667
```